# Autodesk Forge Design Automation getEngines failing

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I downloaded the sample project file provided by Autodesk Forge to implement Design Automation from here: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/tree/nodejs

**Issue:** Getting Error in the DesignAutomation.js on the line code below. The error says 'Forbidden, Not authroized' although I had provided my forge app's token, key and the ngrok url.

***let engines = await api.getEngines({ page: paginationToken });***

I debugged and found that the above line of code is failing and going to the catch exception. Due to this error, I have the 'Select Engines' and 'Existing Activities' dropdown in the UI show up as empty.

Can someone help me with this issue? I'm new with Autodesk Forge and WebAPI, so I'm not able to figure out how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: What does this 
`const api = await Utils.dav3API(req.oauth_token);` 
 returns ? https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/ca21e165a242f5654b1423127e9834c7ec33e9a3/routes/DesignAutomation.js#L204
Hope you set this correctly 


`set FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<<YOUR CLIENT ID FROM DEVELOPER PORTAL>>
set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>>
set FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL=<<YOUR NGROK URL>>`

Comment: It returns an 'apiClient' object. I have set the above listed attributes correctly. So not sure where things are going wrong.

Comment: can you send me your client_id ?, I would like to check if your trail or credits expired. You can drop at     "forge dot help at autodesk dot com"   [no spaces]

Comment: I found that my Forge app trial had got expired, that's why the Design Automation connection has been failing. Thanks Madhukar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the source code, but you can fix it.

The provided source code assumes that you will not change your nickname.
If you don't change your nickname, it will default to your ClientID and the sample code uses this assumption. In the source code, line 57, you will see that:

```
    static get NickName () {
    return (config.credentials.client_id);
   }
```

it assumes that your nickname matches the client_id.

[Check what is your current nickname](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-GET/) by running in terminal (or Postman/Insomnia) the following:

```
curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/forgeapps/me' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN
```

If the provided result doesn't match your ClientId, you can be sure that this is the source of trouble.

In this case, to solve the problem, there are two approaches:

1. Change the code of the **NickName** function (within the source code) to retrieve the nickname (using the above call), instead of just getting the ClientID.
2. [Reset your nickname](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/forgeapps-id-DELETE/), which actually means deleting the activities, bundles and all user stuff. The way to do it is by running:

> curl --request DELETE 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/forgeapps/me' 
> --header 'Authorization: Bearer `$TOKEN​

This will reset your nickname to your ClientID and the code should work fine.

Comment: When I run the nickname code in the terminal, I get the following error.                              

At line:2 char:3
+ --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:2 char:3
+ --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN
+   ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Comment: If you download the sample project and set up following the README.md file, then don't you get this issue as described in my question?